# In Azure App Gateway configured with Helm is there a way to create a Listener for both http and https

Tags: azure

I am configuring an Azure AKS cluster using helm charts for deployment.

When I deploy with appgw-ssl-certificate annotation, I get a listener for https with MyCertificate.

If I deploy without the appgw-ssl-certificate annotation, I get a listener for http with no certificate.

How can I configure this helm chart to create both listeners?

My ingress section looks like this:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: MyCertificate
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-path: "/healthz"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-timeout: "180"
  path: /myapp
  pathType: ImplementationSpecific  
  hosts:
    - myapp.com
```